# Excel Pivot Table - Deactivate colapse/expand function

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I don't want the values to be grouped like they are here:

[image]

I don't want anything grouped with collapse/expand options. I want all columns to be filled with information in all rows, even if it repeats in some fields.

I've tried "Do not show sub-totals" in the "Design" tab and setting the subtotals to none in the Field Settings on the "Analyze" tab, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

- pivottable options - design - report layout - repeat all item labels
- and to hide collapse buttons: pivottable tools - analyze - +/- buttons

---

To add some pictures to the above answer for better help

**In Excel 2016**
In the `Show` group, under the `Analyze` tab, you can toggle the buttons as shown below[image]

**Alternatively**
Right click on the Pivot table and select `Pivot table options` from the right-click-menu,

[image]