# How can I remove the expand/collapse buttons for only some fields in an Excel pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a lot of pivot tables populated from SSAS cubes. Some have expand/collapse buttons for only some of their fields (not the first or second field but then for every other field).

I know how to enable and disable expand/collapse buttons for the whole pivot table (e.g. [Excel Pivot Table - Deactivate colapse/expand function](https://superuser.com/questions/1046795/excel-pivot-table-deactivate-colapse-expand-function/)), but I would like to be able to remove the expand/collapse buttons for just some of the columns in my tables.

The only information I've been able to find about why some fields might not show expand/collapse buttons when they are enabled for the pivot table is this little comment on [Microsoft's support page about enabling and disabling  expand/collapse buttons](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Expand-collapse-or-show-details-in-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-d70d7e70-d230-4d45-81db-1f5e39bcb394):

> NOTE: Expand and collapse buttons are available only for fields that have detail data.

An acceptable answer might be just to explain what that note means :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do this.

The comment you've picked out from Microsoft's support page is simply saying that +/- buttons won't be displayed if there aren't any more child fields to expand to (even if +/- buttons are set as active).

So, if you only have one field in your rows/columns, there will be no +/- buttons. Or, if you have 3 fields selected, the first 2 will have +/- buttons, but the last field will not, because there is no more detail to expand.

Comment: That's disappointing. I would like to do this too on columns where I know there will only be one child underneath so there is nothing to expand/collapse. It's distracting when you have columns just supplying additional details about the same entity